# Cannot fetch messages from Store

Tags: wso2, activemq-classic

I have local installations of wso2ei-6.2.0 and apache-activemq-5.15.10. I configured wso2 installation according to docs (added jars and axis2 transport settings).
Storing a message works fine, but consuming the message with a message processor fails with the following error (and not much more):

`[2020-05-26 16:21:53,865] [] ERROR - JmsConsumer Cannot fetch messages from Store store_exact_upsert`

I checked my java version (1.8.0_251-b11) and turned on all jms related logging but can't find a clue what is wrong.

The message is just a simple soap message (in wso2 message context).

Any ideas how to debug / solve this problem would be helpful.

[I run on Windows 10 version 1909 build 18363.836]

Comment: Hello. I'm facing same issue in my windows machine. Did you find the reason for this issue ? i enabled all most all logs and scanned activemq and wso2 properties with no success !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. when i debug the code, in core module, JMSConsumer class,
developer is not printing the exception's error message. instead they are printing
below generic message which is very misleading.

`JmsConsumer Cannot fetch messages from Store`

In my case, actual exception i saw while debugging was below :

`"java.lang.classnotfoundexception: org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.commons.storablemessage cannot be found by activemq_all_5.11.3_1.0.0".`

I have found the StorableMessage class in the synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v182.jar which i placed in $ACTIVEMQ_ROOT/lib directory. This resolved my issue.

Please check if this is the same issue.